# VSCode cannot see packages on a GCP VM

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have an issue where vscode when connected to a VM on GCP cannot see packages installed in `/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages.` I have created the VM using Vertex AI. When I open the jupyter notebook through the UI in a the browser I can see all the packages via `pip3 list`. But when I am connected to the VM through SSH in vscode I cannot see the packages installed such as nltk, spacy etc. and when I try to load it gives me `ModuleNotFoundError`. This error does not show up when I use the jupyter notebook from the Vertex AI UI. The site-packages folder is in my system path and the python that I am using is `/opt/conda/bin/python3`.

Any help is appreciated. Please do let me know if my question is clear.

EDIT: I figured out that my packages are running on a container in the VM. Is there a way for me to access those packages via jupyter notebook in vscode?

Comment: What environment (Python, Tensorflow, Pytorch, etc.) does your notebook use? Also can you double check if you are doing the SSH to the correct notebook?

Comment: Hi Ricco. I figured it out. I had to install docker extension on my VM then attach VSCode to the container. After that it was smooth sailing. I could install all the extensions and access all my libraries!

Comment: You can post your comment as the answer so when other users encountered the similar problem, the answer could easily be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the answer as community wiki. As confirmed by @Abhishek, he was able to make it work by installing a docker extension on the VM then attach VS code to the container.